# Sed command examples in linux

Tags: sed

I have the file in the name of `file123` with the content of

```
passwd:x:redhat
redhat:x:pass
passwd:x:linux
passwd:x:redhatlinux
```

i want to change the keyword `passwd` inside the file on particularly 1,3 line.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
sed '1,3 s/^passwd/NEW/' file123
```

- `1,3` makes `sed` only to operate on line 1 to 3
- `s/^passwd/NEW/` substitute `passwd` at the start (`^`) with `NEW`, change this to meet your need. Note that although `1,3` is matching from lines 1 to 3, the Regex pattern is only matching line 1 and 3 of your sample, hence modifications are being made to those lines only

To edit the file in place, with the GNU implementation of `sed`:

```
sed -i '1,3 s/^passwd/NEW/' file123
```

Comment: you might want to clarify that `1,3` means lines `1,2,3` but that your regex ensures it works for OP's input

Comment: @spasic Clarified..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a substitution on lines 1 and 3 only, you can do:

```
sed '
  1 b subst
  3 b subst
  b
  :subst
  s/string/replacement/'
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || NR == 3 {sub(/string/, "replacement")}
     {print}'
```